# Error:3003 in flex How to fix it?

Tags: apache-flex

This is the code that I compile in Flash FDT.

[image]

Code is compiled successfully but when I click on button it generate runtime  `Error: Error #3003.`
Please help me to resolve it. My image file is in bin directory.I moved that image file to src directory but still it gives same error.

Comment: Please do not post code as images.  It makes it more difficult for users who face a similar issue in the future to find this question and benefit from the answers.  Please instead post the relevant code directly in the body of the question.

Comment: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/runtimeErrors.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your file "img.jpeg" exists in your documents Directory. If the file do not exists or the name or extension is different, then Error 3003 comes.

I tested your code in my local system and it is working fine. Only issue can be the file is missing in documents directory or name/extension is different(may be jpg instead of jpeg)